# Adding custom font-size option

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to implement a custom font option. In which I enclose selected text in editor in a font tag with style font-size I got the selected content from editor so I created a new font tag and tried to replace the selected content with the new font tag. But some time it is not working. Can someone provide me another way to implement it? If I select a text, it should be enclosed in a font tag with a font size selected by the user.

my Code:

```
function stripHtml(html){
var temporalDivElement = document.createElement("div");
temporalDivElement.innerHTML = html;
return temporalDivElement.textContent || temporalDivElement.innerText || "";}
function SetFontSizeNew(value){
    var theSelectionObject = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
    var Blocks = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getSelectedBlocks();
    var Text=tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format : 'html'}).toString();
    var fontfamily="";
    if($(Blocks[0]).find("font").length>0){
      fontfamily=$(Blocks[0]).find("font")["0"].style.fontFamily;
    }
    else{
       fontfamily=Blocks[0].style.fontFamily;
    }
    var Final="";

    if(theSelectionObject.offsetParent.tagName=="TR"||theSelectionObject.offsetParent.tagName=="TD"||theSelectionObject.offsetParent.tagName=="TABLE")
    {
        var theSelectionObject = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode();                        
        var table=$(theSelectionObject).closest('td');
        var Newtextcontent=stripHtml(Text);
        if(Blocks[0].innerText==Newtextcontent){
            var htmltag=$($($(Blocks[0]))["0"].innerHTML);

            var element=[];

            for(j=0;j<htmltag.length;j++){
                if(htmltag[j].tagName=="FONT"){

                    element.push(htmltag[j]);

                    $(htmltag[j]).css('font-size', value+"pt");
                }
            }

            var eleouterhtml="";

            for(k=0;k<element.length;k++){                        
                $(element[k]).css('font-size', value+"pt");

            }

            for(l=0;l<htmltag.length;l++){
                if(htmltag[l].nodeName=="#text"){
                    eleouterhtml=eleouterhtml+htmltag[l].textContent;
                }
                else{
                    var fonttag=$(htmltag[l]).find('font');
                    $(fonttag).css('font-size', value+"pt");
                    eleouterhtml=eleouterhtml+htmltag[l].outerHTML;          
                }
            }

            if(Blocks[0].childNodes["0"].nodeName=="#text"){
                Final='<font style="font-size:'+value+'pt;font-family:'+ fontfamily.replace(/["]/g, "")+ '" data-mce-style="font-size:'+value+'pt;font-family:'+ fontfamily.replace(/["]/g, "") + '">'+eleouterhtml.trim()+'</font>';
            }
            else{           
                Final=eleouterhtml.trim();
            }

            Blocks[0].innerHTML=Final;

            var newOutput=Blocks[0].outerHTML;

            Blocks[0].outerHTML=newOutput; 

        }
        else{
            if(theSelectionObject.innerHTML==Text){
                $(theSelectionObject).css('font-size', value+"pt");
                Final=Blocks[0].outerHTML;
                Blocks[0].outerHTML=Final; 
            }
            else{                 
                var newFinal='<font style="font-size:'+value+'pt;font-family:'+ fontfamily.replace(/["]/g, "")+ '" data-mce-style="font-size:'+value+'pt;font-family:'+ fontfamily.replace(/["]/g, "") + '">'+Text+'</font>';
                Final=Blocks[0].outerHTML.replace(Text,newFinal);
                Blocks[0].outerHTML=Final; 
            }
        }


    }
    else{
        var Newtextcontent=stripHtml(Text);
        if(Blocks[0].innerText==Newtextcontent){
            var htmltag=$($($(Blocks[0]))["0"].innerHTML);

            var element=[];

            for(j=0;j<htmltag.length;j++){
                if(htmltag[j].tagName=="FONT"){
                    element.push(htmltag[j]);
                }
            }

            var eleouterhtml="";

            for(k=0;k<element.length;k++){                        
                $(element[k]).css('font-size', value+"pt");

            }

            for(l=0;l<htmltag.length;l++){
                if(htmltag[l].nodeName=="#text"){
                    eleouterhtml=eleouterhtml+htmltag[l].textContent;
                }
                else{
                    var fonttag=$(htmltag[l]).find('font');
                    $(fonttag).css('font-size', value+"pt");
                    eleouterhtml=eleouterhtml+htmltag[l].outerHTML;      
                }
            }

            if(Blocks[0].childNodes["0"].nodeName=="#text"){
               Final='<font style="font-size:'+value+'pt;font-family:'+ fontfamily.replace(/["]/g, "")+ '" data-mce-style="font-size:'+value+'pt;font-family:'+ fontfamily.replace(/["]/g, "") + '">'+eleouterhtml.trim()+'</font>';
            }
            else{           

                Final=eleouterhtml.trim();
            }
        }
        else{        
            if(theSelectionObject.innerHTML==Text){
                $(theSelectionObject).css('font-size', value+"pt");
                Final=Blocks[0].outerHTML;
            }
            else{                 
                var newFinal='<font style="font-size:'+value+'pt;font-family:'+ fontfamily.replace(/["]/g, "")+ '" data-mce-style="font-size:'+value+'pt;font-family:'+ fontfamily.replace(/["]/g, "") + '">'+Text+'</font>';
                Final=Blocks[0].outerHTML.replace("&nbsp;"," ").replace(Newtextcontent,newFinal);//this is not working properly

            }
        }
        Blocks[0].outerHTML=Final; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: You need to post some code, tell us what about it is not working. See [instructions for posting to sof](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have posted my code in question